# How do I pass a column to substr function in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 columns in a dataframe, ValueText and GLength. I need to add a new column VX based on other 2 columns (ValueText and GLength). Basically, new column VX is based on substring of ValueText. Below is what I tried

```
df_stage1.withColumn("VX", df_stage1.ValueText.substr(6,df_stage1.GLength))
```

However with above code, I get error: startPos and length must be the same type. Got class 'int' and class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column', respectively.

I have also tried

```
func.expr("substring(ValueText,5, 5 + GLength)")
```

When I execute above code, i get the error: Pyspark job aborted due to stage failure

Comment: Could you try `df_stage1.ValueText.substr(f.lit(6), df_stage1.GLength)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`expr`** will work in this case, as we are using **`Glength`** in substring function.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("abcdff",4),("dlaldajfa",3)],["valuetext","Glength"])
df.show()
#+---------+-------+
#|valuetext|Glength|
#+---------+-------+
#|   abcdff|      4|
#|dlaldajfa|      3|
#+---------+-------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("vx",expr("substring(valuetext,0,Glength)")).show()
#+---------+-------+----+
#|valuetext|Glength|  vx|
#+---------+-------+----+
#|   abcdff|      4|abcd|
#|dlaldajfa|      3| dla|
#+---------+-------+----+
```